# Creating and using DropDown custom extension in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, extension-methods

I thought this would be a standard task but I get a lot of difficulties so I seek for assistance.

I have a drop down that I use intensively in my views and now I have a lot of `@Html.DropDown()` with the same logic in it and I decided that it's a good place to replace this with a custom html extension.

Instead of describing my project structure I'll just post a screenshot of it :

[image: Project Structure]

So in `HtmlExtensions.cs` I've created the method I think I need looking from an example somewhere on the net. The method looks like this :

```
public static MvcHtmlString YesNoNotApplicableDDown(this HtmlHelper html)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create("<select class=\"YesNoNotApplicable\"> <option value=\"1\">Yes</option> <option value=\"2\">No</option><option value=\"3\">NotApplicable</option></select>");
        }
```

Then I add the namespace in my `web.config` under `Views` :

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="MCSResources" />
        <add namespace="MaintenanceCheckSystem.Utils.HtmlExtensions" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

In fact I tried with and without the name of the project at the begining, so I tested this too :

```
<add namespace="Utils.HtmlExtensions" />
```

Then in one of my views I tried `@Html.Ye..` but I don't get no hint, and when I checked my custom method wasn't there. I don't know if I miss something or I did something wrong (maybe both), so how can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Initial answer

Is your extensions-class a public static method? Your sample code doesn't show the class definition.

This is one of the [requirements for extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311042.aspx).

### Update

You say you've added the namespace like this:

```
<add namespace="Utils.HtmlExtensions" />
```

But is that really the namespace? Is the namespace not like simply this:

```
<add namespace="MaintenanceCheckSystem.Utils" />
```

The classname should not be included in the using statement.

Similar if you register the namespace in the web.config, also without the classname.

Comment: Yeah, it is public static.

Comment: You are right. The whole problem was the way I add the namespace. You suggestions is correct. Like this - `<add namespace="MaintenanceCheckSystem.Utils"/>` its all fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: sorry, i copied this namespace. of course ir should be `MaintenanceCheckSystem.Utils`

Answer (score 1):

You can try registering this namespace in the web.config

```
<add namespace="MaintenanceCheckSystem.Utils" />
```

And call your helper in the view like :

```
@HtmlExtensions.YesNoNotApplicableDDown()
```

Comment: Well, this actually works. But can't it be done like real html extension why it's not working the way it should, any ideas?

Comment: I think I know why it is not working. Try to declare your extension in this namespace : namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
You should be able to use your helper like that (and with intellisense !)
`@Html.YesNoNotApplicableDDown()`

Answer (score 0):

write

```
@using MaintenanceCheckSystem.Utils.HtmlExtensions
```

in your .cshtml files

**UPD**: `@using MaintenanceCheckSystem.Utils`

Comment: Tried it. Yet can't access my methods.